# Swift 4.0: How do i move all the NSArray values to NSDictionary dynamically?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsarray, swift4

I have an NSArray it has 10 NSDictionary records.
I need to move all the records to NSDictionary one by one as like we do in Objective c using

```
NSDictionary *dictName = [Array_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Don't know how to do in Swift 4.0.

Comment: you want to move array values to a dictionary? what are the keys going to be?

Comment: Basically don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types. And even in ObjC the modern syntax `Array_name[indexPath.row]` is preferable which is the same in Swift.

Comment: I tried as follows but can't print the values of NSDictionary in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. leadsArray[indexPath.row] as! [NSDictionary]

Comment: If let _ = Array_name[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary { let myDictionary = Array_name[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary this is how you call

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here some examples to use array with dictionaries. Use documentations for your guide always. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array)

```
let arr = [["11":11,"12":12],["21":21,"22":22]]
let dic = arr[0]
let dic1 = arr.first

for item in arr {
    let dic = item
}
```